# Create custom route handler for playframework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, customization, router

I want create a custom router for playframework but when extend `GuiceApplicationLoader` and set `play.application.loader` in configuration override default router.

How create custom router and not override default router.

```scala
class MyApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader with GuiceableModuleConversions {
  override protected def overrides(context: Context): Seq[GuiceableModule] = {
    Seq(fromGuiceModule(new RouterModule)) ++ super.overrides(context)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want load extra routes at runtime  without add line into  routes file.@tomer

Comment: I don't think you can do that :) But I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Tank you @tomer. But I do that.